# How split values of ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am getting a list of data in a loop. For example :

`List<String>` and the values is :

```
abc{+6636593}
jkihe{qwsd223awq}
......
......etc
```

I need to have:

```
abc
jkihe
```

I write this code :

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String valueone : valuetwo){
     values.add(valueone);
}
```

Above code work good but below code get me crash :

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    Log.i("test" , values.get(i).split("{")[0]); <==== HERE GET ME CRASH
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Any error message when your code *gets you crash*?

Comment: How does "code work good" yet also "crash"?

Comment: Why mixing the old fashion for loop with the enhanced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#split()` accepts regex as parameter, you need to escape `{`. 
Try this `Log.i("test" , values.get(i).split("\\{")[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with enhanced `for` loop and without `regex`

```
for(String test: values) {
   Log.i("test", test.replace(test.substring(test.indexOf("{")), ""));
}
```

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: more efficient: `Log.i("test", values.get(i).substring(0, values.get(i).indexOf('{')));`